# when I click on add product the buy button does not work and not show popup

Tags: javascript

There is a problem with my code when I click on an item buy a popup appears but when I click on add product the buy button does not work and does not show popup

html code

```
<body  id="body"  class="light ">
<h5 class="dark-button">dark mode</h5>
<h4 class="add-pro"> add proudct</h4>
 



  <div class="continer">
    <div class="coninar-box">
      <img src="product1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        <h4>product1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing  quae temporibus numquam vero unde consequuntur </p>
<button class="btn">buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="coninar-box">
      <img src="product1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        <h4>product2</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing  quae temporibus numquam vero unde consequuntur </p>
<button class="btn" >buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="coninar-box">
      <img src="product1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        <h4>product3</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing  quae temporibus numquam vero unde consequuntur </p>
<button class="btn" >buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="coninar-box">
      <img src="product1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        <h4>product4</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing  quae temporibus numquam vero unde consequuntur </p>
<button class="btn" >buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="coninar-box">
      <img src="product1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        <h4>product5</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing  quae temporibus numquam vero unde consequuntur </p>
<button class="btn" >buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    

    <div class="pop-one">
      <div class="overlay">
      <h3 id="dd" >you need to buy</h3>
      <div class="nflex">
      <input id="input" type="number" name="" id="">
      <button class="yes">yes</button>
     
    </div>
   
    </div>
    <div class="pop-tow">
      <div class="overlay1">
      <h3 class="last-masseg">you need to buy</h3>
      <div class="nflex">
      
     
     
    </div>
   
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    

   
  </div>
</body>
```

css code

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   
  }

  .continer{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
   
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px){
    .continer{
        width: 750px;
    }
  }
  
  /* medium */
  @media (min-width: 992px){
    .continer{
        width: 970px;
    }
  }
  /* large */
  @media (min-width:1200px){
    .continer{
        width: 1170px;
    }
  }

/* start */
body .continer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}
.coninar-box{
 
    width: 260px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(168, 168, 168);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 13px;
}
.coninar-box img{
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
   width: 260px;
   height: 150px;
}
.coninar-box h4 {
    font-weight: 600;
   
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.coninar-box p {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 2px 10px;
   line-height: 1.6;
   
}

.coninar-box button {
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(8, 79, 212);
    border: transparent;
}
@media (max-width:767px){
    .coninar-box{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .coninar-box img{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* start pop one */

.continer .pop-one {
    
    position: fixed;
    background-color: burlywood;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
z-index:1;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
display: none;
}

.continer .pop-tow h3{
text-align: center;

}
.continer .pop-one h3{
color: rebeccapurple;
margin-bottom: 15px;
text-align: center;
}
.continer .pop-one input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(51, 255, 0);
outline: none;
}

.continer .pop-one .overlay  {
    background-color: rgb(149, 182, 164);
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   
   margin-top: 50px;
    display: none;
    /* to nonn 1 */
}
.continer .pop-tow .overlay1{
    background-color: rgb(149, 182, 164);
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   z-index: 1;
   margin-top: 50px;
  display: none;
}

.continer .pop-one .yes {
padding: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: rgb(8, 79, 212);
color: white;
border: 1px solid  rgb(8, 79, 212) ;
cursor: pointer;

}
.continer .pop-one .btn1:hover{
    background-color: rgb(10, 92, 244);
}


.dark-button{
    background-color: aqua;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 2s;
}
.dark-button:hover{
    background-color: rgb(42, 195, 195);
}

.light{
    transition: all 2s;
}
.dark {
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
    color: white;
    transition: all 2s;

}
.light .dark-button{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(195, 116, 20);
}
.dark .dark-button {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #030303;
    
}
.dark-text{
    display: none;
}
.dark .continer .pop-one {
    background-color: #030303da;
    
}
.dark .continer .overlay {
    background-color: #272727;
   
}
.dark .continer .overlay h3 {
   color: white;
   
}
.dark #input {
    background-color: rgb(94, 81, 81);
    border: 1px solid rgb(88, 79, 79);
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgb(166, 163, 163);
    color: white;
}
.dark .yes{
    background-color: #030303 !important;
    border: 1px solid #030303  !important ;
}
.dark .overlay1 {
    background-color: #272727 !important;
   
}
.dark .last-masseg{
    color: white !important;
}

.no-scroll{
   overflow: hidden;
   
}
.add-pro{
   background-color: orange;
   color: white;
   border: 1px solid orange;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 14px;
 display: inline-block;

}
.add-pro:hover{
   background-color: rgb(242, 160, 7);
   color: white;
}
.add-pro:active{
   background-color: rgb(7, 242, 42);
   border: 1px solid rgb(7, 242, 42);
}
```

javascript code

```
const overlaymain = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0]
const poupcontinar = document.getElementsByClassName("pop-one")[0]
const ovlaySup = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay1")[0]
const input = document.getElementById("input")
const body = document.getElementById("body")
const adpro = document.getElementsByClassName("add-pro")[0]
const continar = document.getElementsByClassName("continer")[0]
const yes = document.querySelector(".yes")

continar.style.border = "2px solid red"


adpro.addEventListener("click", (eo) => {
  const newpro = `
    <div class="coninar-box">
      <img src="product1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">
        <h4>product5</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing  quae temporibus numquam vero unde consequuntur </p>
        <button class="btn">buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
  continar.innerHTML += newpro
})

continar.addEventListener("click", (eo) => {
  if (eo.target.className == "btn") {

    ovlaySup.style.display = "none"
    poupcontinar.style.display = "flex"
    overlaymain.style.display = "block"
    input.value = ''
    
  }
});


const darkModeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("dark-button")[0]
const light = document.getElementsByClassName("light")[0]
const darkText = document.getElementsByClassName("dark-text")

darkModeButton.addEventListener("click", (eo) => {
  light.classList.toggle("dark")
})




  yes.addEventListener("click" , (eo) => { 

      overlaymain.style.display = "none"
      ovlaySup.style.display = "flex"
      
      setTimeout(() => {
          
          poupcontinar.style.display = "none"
          body.classList.remove("no-scroll")
      
      }, 1000);
      
      
       })
```

There is a problem with my code when I click on an item buy a popup appears but when I click on add product the purchase button does not work and does not show popup

Answer (score -1):

Do you want that when you click on buy the product, it is removed from the screen?

Comment: I want when click on the buy button to  show popup  named in my file   pop-one 
but not show and thank you

Comment: The problem occurs when I click on the add product button, the problem occurs, and when I click on buy, nothing happens but it was working before I pressed the add product button